# Zip the whole contents of a server except for www and access-logs symlinks

Tags: terminal, zip

I'm moving an account to another server, and I'm zipping everything in the terminal using the command `zip -r backup.zip *` while on the server's home `/`. The archive was being created, and when it reached `www` which is a symlink, it started all over adding the same folder it added before, but this time with `www/` in front of the them. How can I alter the above command to exclude the two symlinks I mention above?

TIA

Comment: If it's going to another Linux server, then use `tar` instead. `zip` does not store permissions or ownership details of files. Look at its man page. You will also want to exclude certain directories such as `/proc` & `/sys`.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for (from `man zip`):

```
   -y
   --symlinks
          For  UNIX and VMS (V8.3 and later), store symbolic links as such
          in the zip archive, instead of compressing and storing the  file
          referred  to  by  the  link.   This can avoid multiple copies of
          files being included in the archive as zip recurses  the  direc‐
          tory trees and accesses files directly and by links.
```

Or to exclude:

```bash
zip -r backup.zip * -x "www/*"
```

## Demonstration

Let's assume you have the below symlinks/directories:

```bash
$ ls -ld /*
...
lrwxrwxrwx ... /access-logs -> /var/access-logs
lrwxrwxrwx ... /www -> /var/www
...
```

```bash
$ ls -ld /var/*
...
drwxr-xr-x ... /var/access-logs
drwxr-xr-x ... /var/www
...
```

If you want to include both `/var/access-logs` and `/var/www`, but don't want to duplicate their contents, appending `--symlinks` will suffice. `/access-logs` and `/www` will be stored as symlinks in the zip file.

If you also don't want `/var/access-logs`'s content, you can append `-x "/var/access-logs/*"` to zip command and it will be excluded.

## `tar`

**EDIT:** As @Bib pointed out, you can use `tar` which is the de facto command for archiving multiple files in Linux.

`tar` is "no-dereference" (equal to `--symlinks` mode in `zip`) by default, so it will archive symlinks only as symlinks, it won't follow them like `zip` does.

With option `-I`, we can choose a compression program for the archive. `zstd` has a very good ratio and speed. But, if you really care about a small size improvement and don't mind it being much more slower, you can replace `zstd` with `xz`. Note that the command you want to use must be installed.

Archive `/*` excluding `/excluded-dir-1` and `/excluded-dir-2` using `zstd` compression:

```bash
tar cvf backup.tar.zst -I "zstd" --exclude="/excluded-dir-1" --exclude="/excluded-dir-2" /*
```

Extract archive content to `/backup`:

```bash
tar xvf backup.tar.zst -C "/backup"
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Linux system, so excuse my maybe dumb question: How can we also exclude the access-logs symlink folder? How do we separate it from www excluded one?

Comment: zip is the wrong tool to do this & you should be telling the op that.

Comment: @Bib OP didn't mention the new server's OS, so I answered regarding the current knowledge at that time. But you made a good criticism, answer didn't inform OP about existence of a better tool. I added the `tar` section.

Comment: @ceoonum they said the servers home directory was `/` which means is is some form of `unix`, not `Windows`. It is also being asked on `Unix & Linux`, so I fail to see your argument.

Comment: @Bib I fail to see any info regarding the _new_ server. `/` is in the _current_ server.